# Create an Interactive Command Line Interface with C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

I am fairly new to C# and .net as well as Visual Studio as a whole, so I don't know all of the tools available to me. I am trying to create a "computer algebra system" just for the experience and I am having trouble creating some kind of UI for it.

I built a class library with all of my methods and classes but I've just been testing everything on the terminal with a console application in Visual Studio. I want my UI to function like the standard terminal does, where I can type out instructions and receive answers instead of having a predetermined `Console.ReadLine()` statement that shuts the program down after it executes.

I encapsulated everything in a `while` loop that closes when I type "exit" but that doesn't seem like the standard way of doing things. My question is whether there are resources like a tutorial or a general known workflow for creating a fully developed console application in Visual Studio with C# that functions like a computer algebra systems UI does?

Comment: Your while loop to read input and end when "exit" is entered sounds like a perfectly good way to go about doing things. Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins It works sufficiently! I wasn't sure if there was a more standard way of doing it. But I will keep working on the while loop solution. Thank you!